# Go channels unbuffered

Tags: go, channel, unbuffered

```
package main 
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var message chan string

func main() {
    message = make(chan string)
    count := 6
    flag := "first"
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("child go ",flag)
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
            fmt.Println("set:",i)
            message <- fmt.Sprintf("message %d",i)
        }   
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 0)

    fmt.Println("main thread ",flag)
    flag = "last"
    for i := 0 ; i < count; i++ {
        fmt.Println("get:",i)
        fmt.Println(<-message)
    }
}
```

I run the code and the result is:

```
main thread  first
get: 0
child go  last
set: 0
set: 1
message 0
get: 1
message 1
get: 2
set: 2
set: 3
message 2
get: 3
message 3
get: 4
set: 4
set: 5
message 4
get: 5
message 5
```

I am confused by the result. Why does 'message 1' appear after 'get 1' but not 'set 2'? This has puzzled me for several days!

I think when it 'get 1', the main go routine should be blocked and the child go routine should be exec'd, send 'message 1' to channel message and continue the for loop and print 'set 2',thus blocked at send 'message 2' to channel, so main go routine start to run, output 'message 1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does exactly what you think it should do (if I understand what you think it should do): Receiving from `message` blocks until a value was sent. Unfortunately your code prints "set 2" before sending on the channel and this operation is not blocked.

Synchronisation happens only at `<-`, the Println before the channel send can run.
Have a look at http://play.golang.org/p/d6_SkBugqs which prints before and after each send/receive op and you'll see that all is properly sycronised: All "post-recv n" happen after "pre-send n".

Comment: i just wonder why it does not output "set 2" after "get 1",i think "set 2" should bfore "message 1"

Comment: Why? Based on what syncronisation?

Comment: yeah,the output confused me very much,it sucks.

Comment: I look at the result print by the code at http://play.golang.org/p/d6_SkBugqs,it still puzzy.i think the output should be like this "pre-recv 0,pre-send 0,post-send0,pre-send 1,post-recv 0,pre-recv 1,post-send 1,pre-send 2,post-recv 1,pre-recv 2",i wonder why it output "post-recv 1" after "pre-recv 1"?

Comment: Maybe we could help here if you could describe **why** you think that the output should be different. Note: Inside one goroutine the order is basically the source code order, so the code will **always** print "pre-rev <n>" before "post-rev <n>" no matter whether synchronization is used or not. Your desired output *might* be a possible one as for all n "pre-X n" comes before "post-X n" and  "pre-X n+1" come after "post X n".

Comment: when it output "pre-recv 1",main go routine try to read next element from the "message" channel,but it empty now,so it should be blocked,and the kernel swift cpu to child go routine,it send "message 1" to the channel and continue to output "post-send 1,pre-send 2",there it blocked too. thus main go routine continue exec and output "message 1,post-recv 1,pre-recv 2". That's my opinion.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Bot goroutines run (basically) completely independent of each other until both hold at the same synchronization point. After passing this synchronisation they continue to run completely independent.  Goroutine scheduling is not a handover on each channel send/receive.